# Where do I find the Magic: the Gathering article about varying card backs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I remember reading an MTG design article back during the Time Spiral on a what-if scenario where every MTG set would have a different card back.

I've tried looking through the MTG archives, but all I can find is this one;

https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/almost-different-back-2002-08-05

Which talks about how that almost happened, but isn't the expanded article that I remember. Did I imagine this?

(I hope this is on topic, but I'm afraid it might not be as it's a question about an article about a game, rather than a question about a game.)

Comment: [Game-adjacent questions are on topic here](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/5573), so asking about finding this article is OK.

Comment: I also distinctly remember seeing an article about that a while ago. I also know there was a video from The Misprint Guy where he talked about alternate card _frames_, but I don't remember if he also said anything about the backs. I'll try to find some of those.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything, but try looking for articles related to a sixth color, since that's what would have prompted the Time Spiral back change

Answer (score 1):

I've found a couple of articles on MtG's card backs, aside from that one in your original post.

One of them is fairly old, from 2002, and it talks about [how Arabian Nights was conceived](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-arabian-nights-2002-08-05).

The second one is from October 2017, where Wizards of the Coast [unveiled their new MtG logo](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/raising-new-banner-2017-10-08). This one specifically talks about how they have *no intention* about changing the card backs at any point for the foreseeable future.

I'm still on the hunt for the specific article you mentioned, but I've not yet managed to find it.

Comment: I think I linked the 2002 one in the question. I am reasonably certain it should have been early 2007 near the "Space:The convergence" article. I am starting to think I imagined it.